# Safari - ignore pinned tabs when switching via cmd-number

Tags: keyboard, safari, shortcut, tabs

Is there a way to ignore pinned tabs when switching via the cmd-number shortcuts, e.g. if I have two pinned tabs and press cmd+1, instead of opening the first pinned tab - open the first regular tab.

Thanks!

Comment: A cool thing would to be able to pin tabs to the right of the window so that only higher numbers (e.g starting from 7 if you only have 3 pinned tabs) will trigger those tabs